# Restangular POST not passing data parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, restangular

I'm new to using restangular. With that said, I have the below POST call which for some reason is not working as expected.

```
Restangular.all("user").all("login").post({username: 'test@user.com', password: 'xyz'}).then(function(account)
{ 
     console.log(account);
});
```

I see the POST request going out to the url **/api/v1/user/login** which is the correct url. However, the post parameters don't appear to be getting passed. Looking at that same POST request I don't see the username/password data. In addition, my API is throwing an unauthorized error which says to me it is unable to validate the user based on credentials.

I have also tried variants as follows...

```
Restangular.one("user").post("login", {username: 'test@user.com', password: 'xyz'}).then(function(account)
{ 
    console.log(account);

})
```

Still the post data doesn't appear to be getting sent. I have also tried...

```
Restangular.all("user").post("login", {username: 'test@user.com', password: 'xyz'}).then(function(account)
{ 
    console.log(account);

})
```

That appears to create an incorrect url **/api/v1/user** and no post data is still not visible.

I can perform cURL POST requests to **/api/v1/user/login** passing in the POST data without issue.

```
cURL -X POST /api/v1/user/login -d "username=test@user.com&password=xyz"
```

I also updated my curl statement as @David suggested in his answer to...

```
curl -X POST -d '{"username": "test@user.com", "password": "xyz"}' '/api/v1/user/login' -H Content-Type:application/json
```

Which still worked. However, posting with restangular doesn't...

```
Restangular.all("user").post("login", {username: 'test@user.com', password: 'xyz'}).then(function(account)
    { 
        console.log(account);

    })
```

Additional ideas?

Comment: Just faced the same restangular behaivior. Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem too, is there any answer for this? I mean is it restangular can't pass body parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Restangular but it seems `.all()` creates a full set of REST APIs for an object.  In this case I think you only want to call `.all()` on "user" and use login as a subresource.

```
var users = Restangular.all("user");

users.post('login', {
  username: 'test@user.com',
  password: 'xyz'
}).then(...);
```

Also you need to make sure your server actually has a `POST /users/login` endpoint.

Comment: thanks I have tried that variant but, still doesn't work. I've updated my question to include additional details.

Answer (score 0):

I see that's one year old question but anyway. I have faced the same issue and I bielive I found solution for this problem. The all thing is in Restangular.setRequestInterceptor event. So if you have a such interceptor in your code then you need to be sure that it returns accepted element parameter after your required actions was made. For example that's what I had before:

```
Restangular.setRequestInterceptor(function () {
            $rootScope.validationErrors = [];
            activeRequests++;
            $rootScope.loading = true;          
        })
```

And that's what should be done with it:

```
Restangular.setRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, what, url) {
        $rootScope.validationErrors = [];
        activeRequests++;
        $rootScope.loading = true;
        return element;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending incorrectly the post params, you have:

```
Restangular.all("user").all("login")
.post({username: 'test@user.com', password: 'xyz'})
.then(function(account) { 
    console.log(account); 
});
```

So, you need to make a little change and it will be works (send body params correctly):

```
Restangular.all("user").all("login")
.post('', {username: 'test@user.com', password: 'xyz'})
.then(function(account) { 
    console.log(account); 
});
```

Note: I tried it on restangular v1.5.2

Good luck!